# How to Access a Specific memory location with GDB

Tags: c, linux, memory, gdb, reverse-engineering

This may be a noob question. Am completely new to GNU debugger. I only used Immunity in past.

[GDB Dump (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BX9HR.png)

How do i get the Address of `0x42424242`?

Printing `0xffffd280` only displays `0x41414141`.

Comment: 0xfffffd280.. 0xfffffd283 contains 0x41414141 according to your screenshot. The circled 0x42424242 is at 0xffffd28c..0xffffd28f

Answer (score 1):

Well, the address will be there pointed by **EIP** if you set a breakpoint at `0x42424242` and then do `info registers`. Find **EIP** in the output, and that will be your address.